# How can I disable clear of clipboard on exit of PyQt application?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, clipboard

I have a simple PyQt4 application (see the code below) that reveals a problem: if I select the text from a `QLineEdit` and copy it to the clipboard, then I can paste it to another application only while my application is running. It seems that on exit, PyQt application clears the clipboard so I can't paste the text after the application is closed.

What can I do to avoid this problem?

PyQt 4.4.3 @ Python 2.5 @ Windows XP. Also this effect confirmed on PyQt 4.5+, and on Linux too.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
edit.setText('foo bar')
edit.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: PRIMARY and SECONDARY selections do not survive after the programs they were selected in exit on X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, there is not exactly clear of clipboard occurs. Just QT store some sort of pointer of text in the clipboard instead of just text. Gordon Tyler has pointed me to [this discussion on the PyQt mailing list](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2009-April/022857.html) which explains what's going on. I quote code and relevant part of explanation.

Run this code on exit of application (e.g. in closeEvent handler):

```
   from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
   clipboard = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()
   event = QtCore.QEvent(QtCore.QEvent.Clipboard)
   QtGui.QApplication.sendEvent(clipboard, event)
```

> The basic concept behind this is that by default copying something
>   into the clipboard only copies a reference/pointer to the source
>   application. Then when another application wants to paste the data
>   from the clipboard it requests the data from the source application.
>   Calling [OleFlushClipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679707(VS.85).aspx) causes Windows to copy the real data
>   into the clipboard instead of the reference. While this does cause a
>   delay when copying images, it should not have any noticeable impact
>   with strings.

The code above is pretty cross-platform and don't make any bad impact on Linux platform.

Comment: This won't work on other platforms if there's no clipboard manager available.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question when I ran into similar issue under GNU/Linux and found the answer on the site referenced by bialix (whose address has changed, but can still be reached via web search). To cite the most relevant part:

> Remember that in Linux, unless you have something like klipper, when the app setting the clipboard exits, the clipboard empties.

So there's that. It's a system thing for GNU/Linux. Here's a more thorough explanation from [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence):

> Why does this happen?
>
> The problem happens because Xorg takes a conservative approach to copying. It copies only a reference to the original data when the user performs a select or copy. It doesn't go and retrieve the actual data from the source program until the user requests a paste. It saves a lot of unneeded transfer of data this way, at the expense of having no way of retrieving data from a closed program that hasn't saved its clipboard somewhere else.

You can get around it by installing a clipboard manager such as parcellite, klipper, glipper or clipman.