# How to keep the clipboard when the application exits

Tags: gtk, clipboard

This is basically the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007103/how-can-i-disable-clear-of-clipboard-on-exit-of-pyqt4-application) but for GTK+ instead of Qt.

How can I prevent the clipboard from being cleared when the application exits?

Answer (score 1):

The code sample shown in the accepted answer is for Windows only. GTK+ [already preserves the clipboard itself when `gtk_main()` returns](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkmain.c) where it can; you don't have to do anything special (but you do have to return from `gtk_main()`, so don't call `exit()` from within a signal handler).

As for Unix platforms, rr-'s answer there still applies: there's no way for you to do this on Linux and other such Unixes because X11 itself is wiping your clipboard when the program quits. You will need to have a clipboard manager installed.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that using a clipboard manager fixes this issue on Unixes. However, Firefox does preserve the clipboard without a clipboard manager, so I wonder how it does this. Do you think that using `XStoreBytes` or the cut buffer will do it?