# How to use PyQt5 to set system clipboard without event loop?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

How to use Pyqt5 to set system clipboard and quit as soon as possible? `QCoreApplication` doesn't come with clipboard support, so the choice should be `QApplication`.

The following code is not working without starting event loop `app.exec_()`. But all I need is to set the clipboard and quit the script as soon as possible.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication([])
app.clipboard().setText('test')
# sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I follow the instruction from [How can I disable clear of clipboard on exit of PyQt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007103/how-can-i-disable-clear-of-clipboard-on-exit-of-pyqt-application?).

The following two methods don't work either.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent

app = QApplication([])
cb = QApplication.clipboard()
cb.setText('test01')
event = QEvent(QEvent.Clipboard)
app.sendEvent(cb, event)
app.processEvents()
```

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QTimer

app = QApplication([])
cb = QApplication.clipboard()
cb.setText('test02')
QTimer.singleShot(0, app.quit)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: NB: if you're on linux, make sure you read **all** the answers to the linked duplicates.

Comment: @ekhumoro I am not so sure it is duplicated.The other two address on preserve copied data after quit. My problem is I run the script from Windows command line, don't want to invoke the event loop (quit the script as soon as possible), without mannully closing the app.

Comment: But that is **exactly** why your example doesn't work. Try the solution given in the first duplicate if you are on windows.

Comment: @ekhumoro I updated my question per your instruction. It doesn't work. Could you give more tips?

Comment: Try adding `app.processEvents()` at the end. Alternatively, you could add `QTimer.singleShot(0, app.quit); app.exec()`, which will automatically terminate the event-loop. But that assumes the `QEvent` hack still works in Qt5. If not, you'll have to forget about PyQt and use some other third-party clipboard solution.

Comment: try with: `import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    cb = QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard()
    text = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, partial(cb.setText, text))
    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(QtWidgets.QApplication.quit)
    cb.dataChanged.connect(partial(timer.start, 10))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())`

Comment: @eyllansesc with on luck. Does this work on your platform? Mime is Windows 10.

Comment: @minion Try changing the 10 to an appropriate value, for my case (KDE, ArchLinux) that value is adequate, although as noted by ekhumoro it is better to look for a library that uses the tools of your OS, in the case of Qt everything works from an eventloop so you have to wait some time (there is no certainty of how much time it is since for a GUI it is not a priority).

Comment: @eyllanesc On X11, the clipboard contents will always be cleared when an application closes unless some third-party utility explicitly copies the data beforehand. Your system must therefore have a clipboard manager installed which is automatically storing the data. The question is whether this works in a similar way on windows. Previously, a little hack was needed to force the windows clipboard manager to store the data - but it seems that doesn't work any more (I can't test this myself, though).

Comment: @ekhumoro interesting, that I did not know, and probably yes, my system has an application that shows the clipboards that are probably retaining the data of other applications.