# How to prevent PyQt app from clearing clipboard at exit?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, clipboard

I'm writing a PyQt5 app that includes some text widgets.  If I copy some text to the clipboard, I can paste it into other programs only while my program is running.  If I close my program, its clipboard data disappears.

I see there is [an open Qt bug about this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11616) which suggests calling the Windows API `OleFlushClipboard`, but I am looking for a cross-platform solution.

My question is basically identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007103/how-can-i-disable-clear-of-clipboard-on-exit-of-pyqt-application), but the answer there is over 10 years old and it doesn't seem to work anymore.  I put that code in my program at various positions (in a closeEvent handler, in another function that I called manually just to test it, etc.) and it doesn't flush the clipboard.

My test code is basically identical to that from the old question, but updated for PyQt5:

```
import sys
import random

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
print("Qt Version", QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)
print("PyQt Version", QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR)
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
edit.setText('try copying this random number {}'.format(random.randint(1, 1000)))
edit.show()
app.exec_()
```

If I run this and copy the text from the QLineEdit, then close the app, I can't paste the data anywhere; it's gone.  If I run it, copy the text, paste it into another app (before closing my PyQt5 test program) and *then* close my test program, I get strange and inconsistent behavior where I can paste into some apps but not others.  It seems I can usually continue to paste into whatever app I pasted into before closing my test program, but pasting into other apps is hit or miss.  But the bottom line is that I want pasting to always work into any app regardless of when I closed my Qt program relative to the paste and Qt isn't making that work.

Is there any cross-platform way to force Qt to stop storing "pointers" to clipboard data and to immediately put the actual copied data into the actual system clipboard?  I would prefer not to rely on something like closeEvent but to instead completely disable whatever fancy stuff Qt is doing and have it always immediately put the actual data directly into the system clipboard on every clipboard event without ever maintaining any kind of control or pointer handling (so even if I force-killed my Qt app and it didn't get to "clean up" and flush the clipboard on exit, the data would still be on the clipboard). I'm testing this on Windows but I want a solution that works for at least Windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: Do you mean copying from e.g. QLineEdit or via clipboard = QApplication.clipboard() and             clipboard.setText("test"). In both cases, on Windows OS text remains in the global Windows clipboard after the PyQt5 app is finished.

Comment: @nenad: I mean copying using Ctrl+C or the like.  I included a code example with some more details on the behavior.